# How to create a Swift Pod which contains a Objective-C framework?

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I need to create a Swift Pod for my Swift project, but I need to contain a Objective-C framework in this Pod.

but in my pod development pod, I don not know how to reference this Objective-C framework, what should I do? or any advice? or something wrong with my .podspec?

here is my project: https://github.com/huangxinyu1213/HHTencentOpenApiSDK

Comment: By swift pod do you mean that you created a swift framework or a normal swift app project?

Comment: yes, I create a Swift pod including a Objective-C framework, I want reference OC's Header, but I cannot create a Bridge-Header in this Swift Pod.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include your objective c headers in a bridging header file,in your pod project,
 for more read that article 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: In a Swift Pod, Can I create a bridging header file?